# Callback function for tar extraction

Tags: embedded-linux, tar, busybox

I'm on a embedded system with busybox an want to extract a very big tar.gz file. At the moment I'm doing this with the tar command.

But this takes several minutes and the user of the device doesn't have access to the console so I want to give a feedback about the uncompression status through another channel. The best thing would be a kind of callback mechanism for each extracted file. Does something like that exist? I have nothing but busybox and a c/c++ compiler for this plattform available. A scriptable tool like tar would be the best.

Comment: Maybe you could use `popen` to read the output of tar command, and do what you will with it in C/C++ code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

`tar -xzf test.tar.gz --checkpoint=100 --checkpoint-action='ttyout=|'`

it will track current progress (tar extraction) with `|` symbol, `--checkpoint-action` is kinda callback and `--checkpoint` is checking time granularity control parameter.

Comment: Nice solution, didn't knew about those parameters. Unfortunately it looks like the current tar version of busybox doesn't support this parameter. Maybe I can port the current version of tar.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question, `--checkpoint` is specific to GNU tar.